# jQuery not recognizing (+) plus sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a calculator program and am having trouble with the addition function. I have the other functions working ("/", "-", "*"), but the plus("+") won't function. The html and JavaScript are included below...

```
<head>

  <title>RDaniels34 | Calculator</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Bitter:400,400italic|Josefin+Sans:400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <style>
    <!-- #main {
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 3px solid #c3c3c3;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        /* Safari */
        -webkit-flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
        /* Safari 6.1+ */
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }

      #main div {
        width: 55px;
        height: 50px;
      }  -->
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightyellow;">
  <header>
    <div class="header-div">
      <h1>Calculator</h1>
      <h3>Made by: RDaniels34</h3>
    </div>
  </header>

  <container class="container">

    <div class="well well-lg" id="numberDisplay">
      <div id="numberDisplay1">0</div>
      <br>
      <div id="numberDisplay2">0</div>
    </div>

    <div id="separator-line"></div>

    <div id="buttonGroup">
      <button type="button" onclick="clrFunction()" id="clr" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">C</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="divideFunction()" id="operators" class="divideNum operators btn btn-default btn-sm">/</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="timesFunction()" id="operators" class="timesNum btn btn-default btn-sm ">X</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="backspaceFunction()" id="backspace" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-caret-left" style="font-size:20px"></button>
      <button type="button" onclick="sevenFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">7</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="eightFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">8</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="nineFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">9</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="addFunction()" id="addNum" class="addNum btn btn-default btn-sm">+</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="fourFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">4</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="fiveFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">5</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="sixFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">6</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="subtractFunction()" id="minusNum" class="minusNum btn btn-default btn-sm">-</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="oneFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">1</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="twoFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">2</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="threeFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">3</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="percentFunction()" id="operators" class="percentNum btn btn-default btn-sm ">%</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="zeroFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm">0</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="decimalFunction()" id="numbers" class="numbers btn btn-default btn-sm ">.</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="plusminusFunction()" id="operators" class="operators btn btn-default btn-sm">+/-</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="rd34Function()" id="rd34" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">RD</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="equalsFunction()" id="equals" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">=</button>
    </div>
  </container>


  <div id="footer">
    Copyright © RDaniels34 - 2016
  </div>

  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

    JS
    $(document).ready(function() {



  var testNumLength = function(firstNumber) {
    if (firstNumber.length > 10) {
      $("#numberDisplay2").text(firstNumber.substr(firstNumber.length - 10, 10));
      if (firstNumber.length > 15) {
        $("#numberDisplay1").text(firstNumber.substr(firstNumber.length - 15, 15));
        firstNumber = "";
        $("#numberDisplay2").text("Err");
      }
    }
  };

  var firstNumber = "";
  var secondNumber = "";
  var answer = "";
  var newAnswer = "";
  var operator = "";




  $("#numberDisplay2").text("");

  $(".numbers").click(function() {
    firstNumber += $(this).text();
    $("#numberDisplay2").text(firstNumber);
    testNumLength(firstNumber);
  });

 // $(".operators").click(function() {
 //   operator = $(this).text();
 //   secondNumber = firstNumber;
 //   firstNumber = "";
 //   $("#numberDisplay2").text();
 // });

  $(".addNum").click(function() {
    operator = $(this).text(); 
    secondNumber = firstNumber;
    firstNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text();
  });

  $(".minusNum").click(function() {
    operator = $(this).text();
    secondNumber = firstNumber;
    firstNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text();
  });

  $(".divideNum").click(function() {
    operator = $(this).text();
    secondNumber = firstNumber;
    firstNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text();
  });

  $(".timesNum").click(function() {
    operator = $(this).text();
    secondNumber = firstNumber;
    firstNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text();
  });

  $(".percentNum").click(function() {
    operator = $(this).text();
    secondNumber = firstNumber;
    firstNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text();
  });


  $("#clr").click(function() {
    firstNumber = "";
    $("#numberDisplay2").text("0");
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "clr") {
      firstNumber = "";
    }
  });

  $("#backspace").click(function() {
    firstNumber = firstNumber.substring(0, firstNumber.length - 1);
    document.getElementById("numberDisplay2").innerHTML = firstNumber;
    testNumLength(firstNumber);
  });

  $("#equals").click(function() {

    parseFloat(firstNumber);
    parseFloat(secondNumber);

    if (operator == "+") {
      answer = secondNumber + firstNumber;
    } else if (operator == "-") {
      answer = secondNumber - firstNumber;
    } else if (operator == "X") {
      answer = secondNumber * firstNumber;
    } else if (operator == "/") {
      answer = secondNumber / firstNumber;
    } else if (operator == "%") {
      answer = secondNumber / 100;
    }
      newAnswer = answer;
    $("#numberDisplay2").text(answer.toPrecision(5));
    testNumLength(answer); 
  }); 
  });
```

Comment: what does it do instead of functioning?

Comment: A link to my CodePen is: http://codepen.io/RDaniels34/pen/MKXOKx

Comment: It's like jQuery doesn't like the "+" sign

Comment: I just ran your CodePen example, and when I do `8 + 5 = `, I get console errors. I'd start with sorting those console errors out.

Comment: does it give more specific details? The other functions are set up exactly the same... ugh....

Comment: It does give specific details but the comment area is too short for me to paste them. Go to your codepen, run it, open up the console, and try adding two numbers. You'll see two console errors which are fairly clear.

Comment: I'll give that a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At line 206 of your js

```
if (operator == "+") {
      answer = secondNumber + firstNumber;
    } else if (operator == "-") {
....
```

try putting this instead

```
    if (operator == "+") {
      answer = parseFloat(firstNumber) + parseFloat(secondNumber);
    } else if (operator == "-") {
....
```

It is likely that the compiler is treating the "+" as concatenation and not a mathematical operation.

### EDIT

This is me being very nitpicky and an annoying busybody but you could probably also simplify many of your buttons to use something like

```
  <button type="button" onclick="addToDisplay(' / ')" id="operators" class="divideNum operators btn btn-default btn-sm">/</button>

<button type="button" onclick="addToDisplay(' X ')" id="operators" class="timesNum btn btn-default btn-sm ">X</button>
```

and

```
function addToDisplay(value){
  //your code here
}
```

Since many of the button functions are almost exactly the same.

Comment: That was it!! I'm SO excited! You were exactly right. I had read other things about the plus sign  acting up with jQuery, but couldn't find my way around it. Thanks again! Two thumbs up!!

Comment: Thanks for the added edit, I will definitely look into that. I'm fairly new at this, but also very passionate about learning all I can about it. Thanks again!